# didReceiveRemoteNotification not working Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NSNotificationCenter
            .defaultCenter()
            .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.tokenRefreshNotificaiton),
                         name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)

        return true
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {


        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print(error)
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
    }


    func tokenRefreshNotificaiton(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
            else {
                return
        }
        //refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        utill.tokenDefault.setValue(refreshedToken, forKey: "tokenId")
        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }


    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device

Everything works fine with sending push notification to other device and even popup notification coming if we send message directly from `Firebase` account. But `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not getting called while receiving notification.

Comment: Share the code of the said delegate method and also show us how you have configured your project for remote push notifications

Comment: I am not able to get that the problem is in our server side or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. Could you give a little more context as to the case in which this is happening? didReceiveRemoteNotification doesn't get called when sending from Firebase console only? @Rinki

Comment: code is working , its calling didReceiveRemoteNotification while receiving message  but the device is  not showing the pop up notification.

Comment: the problem is basically on payload msg format, it should be {
    aps = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        sound : ""
    };
}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("Handle push from foreground")
    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
 }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Handle push from background or closed")
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
    print("\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}
```

Add this code to your app delegates before that you have to add two notification framework in your application.

1.UserNotificationUI.framework
2.UserNotification.framework