# I am working on push notification with firebase. and my "didReceiveRemoteNotification" function is not called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on push notification with firebase. and my "didReceiveRemoteNotification" function is not called.i do not know why my function is not called and also payload data is not recieved in console.please resolve my issue.Thanks in advance.

```
**Here is my code:**
    FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

        // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], 
categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_notifications]
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NotificationCenter.default
        .addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(AppDelegate.tokenRefreshNotification),
                     name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, 
object: nil)

 @objc func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: UIViewController)
    {
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "Testing")
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification 
userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])
{
    print("userInfo\(userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: Did you see this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280986/didreceiveremotenotification-not-working-swift

Comment: This is not working. please provide other information about why payload data is not receiving in console. #Manish Mahajan

Comment: @SanpreetSingh are you testing on simulator?

Comment: No testing on Real device. #Khushbhu

Answer (score 1):

import UserNotifications

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
 if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
    }
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    registerForPushNotifications(application: application)
```

//MARK: pushNotifications methods:

```
func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
            if (granted) {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            } else{
                //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
            }
        })
    } else { //If user is not on iOS 10 use the old methods we've been using


    }
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    let dic = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary
    if let aps = dic["aps"] as? [String: Any] {
        print(aps)
    }
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    print(notification.request.content.userInfo)
    let dic = notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary
    if let aps = dic["aps"] as? [String: Any] {
        print(aps)

    }
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // Print notification payload data
    print("Push notification received: \(data)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `didreceiveremotenotification completionhandler` method. Don't forget to enable the push notifications capability in capabilities tab of your project settings section.